# Accessing abstract class variable from main method

Tags: java, arrays, class, abstract

I am sort of new to the object oriented programming in Java, so I will do my best to explain my problem. I have an abstract class that contains an array of integers as well as two methods that will use that array. The array is unfilled until told to do so.

I ask the user how many elements they would like in the array, and then fill it. There are two methods that are supposed to manipulate the array that is given. The problem is that I don't know how to assign the array to the abstract class so that the same array is carried other into my two methods.

**My Abstract Class**

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass {

    public int[] a;

    //Extend this class and implement the following methods:
    abstract public int selection1(int N);
    abstract public int selection2(int N);
}
```

**My Class Containing Main**

```
public class CreateArray extends MyAbstractClass {

CreateArray myArray = new CreateArray();

public int selection1(int N) {

    int[] arr = myArray.a;

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    return N;
}

public int selection2(int N) {
    int[] arr = myArray.a;

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));

    return N;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("How many elements would you like in your array?: ");
    int numberOfElements = scnr.nextInt();

    //I am unable to access myArray so I can fill the array with numbers   

    fillArray(myArray.a, numberOfElements);

    myArray.selection1(numberOfElements);
    myArray.selection2(numberOfElements);

}

    public static int[] fillArray(int[] arr, int numOfElements) {
    for(int i = 0; i < numOfElements; i++) {
        arr[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

}

What am I missing here? Is this the proper way of doing this? The two print statements that print myArray.a should be printing the same array.

Comment: Isn't it just `myarray.a = new int[] {2, 3, 4 };`? I would not declare non-final member variables public.

Comment: declare myArray as static

Comment: Thank you! It now recognizes myArray. Unfortunately though I get a NullPointer exception upon trying to fill my array.

Comment: I have added the function that fills my array in case this helps.